# How can I get "first" and "second" with a JavaScript regular expression in "This is my first sentence. This is my second sentence."?

Tags: javascript, regex

how can i get "first" and "second" with javascript regular expression in "This is my first sentence. This is my second sentence."

you can try it here on this website [regular website](https://regex101.com/)

**For example** 
 in python `"(?<=(This is)).*?(?=sentence)"`,this will work;but i dont know how to write this with javascript

Comment: can you provide some example ?

Comment: If you already know it is "first" and "second" why would you need a regexp or something? :)

Comment: Learning about regular expressions, doing minimal research and/or trial and error might help.

Comment: @prasad in python this will like this (?<=(This is)).*?(?=sentence) but i dont know how to do it in javascript

Comment: @YuryTarabanko in python this will like this (?<=(This is)).*?(?=sentence) but i dont know how to do it in javascript

Comment: @YuryTarabanko this is just an example, i  have a long string to deal with

Comment: @JackieWillen Here you could read how this would be in javascript. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: can anyone help me,i have work with this problem for one day.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko if you feel simple,you can try it, i have work with this for one day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern `\w+(?=(\s+)?sentence)`

**[Demo regex](https://regex101.com/r/FweSov/3/)**

1. **Positive Lookahead** `(?=(\s+)?sentence)`
2. 1st Capturing Group `(\s+)?`
   `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
3. `\s+` matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
4. `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   sentence matches the characters sentence literally (case insensitive)

```js
var a = 'This is my first sentence.This is my second sentence'

console.log(a.match(/\w+(?=(\s+)?sentence)/ig))
```

**[Updated regex](https://regex101.com/r/FweSov/4/)**  do with while  loop and push the value  to array

```js
var s = '</span><span>wanna-string-a</span></a></span><span>wanna-string-b</span></a></span><span>wanna-string-c</span></a>';

var qualityRegex = /<span>(.*?)<\/span>/g;
var matches;
var qualities = [];

while (matches = qualityRegex.exec(s)) {
  qualities.push(matches[1]);
}

console.log(qualities)
```

Comment: awesome,thank you.this is just an example.the real question is how to get the string between </span><span>wanna-string</span></a>.i want to get wanna-string between ,how can i get it.thank you!

Comment: hello,sorry to disturb you.the result i want to get is an array with string.match.for example </span><span>wanna-string-a</span></a>
</span><span>wanna-string-b</span></a>
</span><span>wanna-string-c</span></a> i want to get [wanna-string-a,wanna-string-b,wanna-stirng-c]

Comment: my try is at here http://regex.zjmainstay.cn/r/mxdMbY/2  i want the full match is wanna-string-a.....

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: my god,you are very very very awesome.thank you very very much.

Comment: you are welcome..my answer is useful mark it  answer.. its helpful future visitors